# How do I find a random color in C#

Tags: c#, colors, background

I a m working on a game application in which if you win the game the background of the screen rapidly changes colors. How would I make the background of my windows form show a random color??

I though maybe I could use the

```
Random i = new Random()
```

method, but I'm not quite sure how I could use that to make a color??

Comment: Consider [Color.FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833(v=vs.110).aspx) - then specify the appropriately-ranged random value, masking the alpha as desired. (But random-random colors aren't always the prettiest.)

Comment: Well, if colors are based on *numbers* and Random gives you a random number, you could generate some random numbers and use them to construct colors. if you run into problems after coding come ask a question. Read the documentation for `Random` and `Color` classes on MSDN.

Comment: Just show how you would create a color from some ints, the rest is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in this way

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

color= Color.FromArgb(this.rand.Next(256), this.rand.Next(256), this.rand.Next(256));
```

refer here for documentation about [Color.FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx)

you can create the color in 3 differents overloads with this function (using only int32)

1. one integer --> Creates a Color structure from a 32-bit ARGB value.
2. three integers --> Creates a Color structure from the specified 8-bit color values (red, green, and blue). The alpha value is implicitly 255 (fully opaque). Although this method allows a 32-bit value to be passed for each color component, the value of each component is limited to 8 bits.
3. four integers--> Creates a Color structure from the four ARGB component (alpha, red, green, and blue) values. Although this method allows a 32-bit value to be passed for each component, the value of each component is limited to 8 bits.

Answer (score 2):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Color c = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(0xFFFFFF + 1)); // assuming you do not want any transparency
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this quite recently! Here is a code snippet. You need to use a Hexideximal code

```
 string color = "";
                Random rand = new Random();
                color = string.Format("#{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", rand.Next(0, 9), rand.Next(0, 9), rand.Next(0, 9), rand.Next(0, 9), rand.Next(0, 9), rand.Next(0, 9));
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(color);
```

to make is flash rapidly, you need to use a loop or a timer to repeat this code over and over

Comment: hm, a timer? I have not used that before! Where do I find it?

Comment: If you go to view->other windows->toolbox you can find timers there

Comment: This won't even select all random colors - it will be very biased towards dim colors.